# Twig question; How can i define classes (or any attributes) dynamically using twig variables

Tags: attributes, twig

I can output the contents of a twig variable as follows:

{{ twig_variable }}

How can i define classes (or any attributes) dynamically using twig variables? the following line obviously fails but i hope it illustrates what i am trying to acheive.

```
<div {{ attributes.addClass(['class1', 'class2', {{ twig_variable }}]) }}></div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `{{ .. }}` around `twig_variable` as you are already inside a `twig` statement

Answer (score 0):

You are triying to add a twig syntax inside twig. Multiple classes can be set like this:

```
   {% set twigvar = 'myvar' %}
   {%
      set classes= [
        'class1',
        'class2,
        twigvar 
      ]
    %}

<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}></div>
```

Comment: using this example local variables works fine doesn't work for imported twig variables.